# How to apply check to select only simple strings and neglect the strings containing date?

Tags: c#

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>()
{
    "element1", "02/18/2019", "element3", "03/17/2018"
};
```

In the above list I want to filter only element1 and element 3 and not the strings containing date. How Can I do that as I have no idea about that.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110408/check-if-a-string-is-in-a-specific-date-format) might be a good starting point.

Comment: It sounds contradictory when you want to "neglect strings containing date" and "filter only element1 and element 2 and not the strings containing date".

Comment: Also, strings don't contain dates. They are just a list of characters. You may be able to parse a string into a date. It appears that your strings could be parsed into dates in the form of `MM/dd/yyyy`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains date or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280265/check-if-a-string-contains-date-or-not)

Comment: Regex way: `var strList = mylist.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"^.*?[A-Za-z]\d+$"));`

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>()
{
    "element1", "02/18/2019", "element3", "03/17/2018"
}.Where(c => !DateTime.TryParse(c, out DateTime d)).ToList();
```

Edit: since the format is consistently MM/dd/yyyy, this should work regardless of the thread's locale:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>()
{
    "element1", "02/18/2019", "element3", "03/17/2018"
}.Where(c => 
    !DateTime.TryParseExact(c, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime d)
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Running `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", mylist));` after your code results in: `"element1,02/18/2019,element3,03/17/2018"`. See [this example](https://rextester.com/FNHR23996) - My assumption is that it's because there isn't a 17th or 18th month.

Comment: @John what's your locale?

Comment: English (United Kingdom)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTime.TryParse` in a loop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_DateTime__

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "element1", "02/18/2019", "element3","03/17/2018" });
var filteredLst = mylist.Where(_ => !DateTime.TryParseExact(_,  "MM/dd/yyyy" ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out DateTime res)).ToList();
```

If you can be 100% certain of the date formats, you better use the `TryParseExact` flavor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8